# Get data from WFS using geotools java library

Tags: java, geotools

I am trying to get features for feature type from WFS using geotools library [gt-wfs-ng v 25.2](https://repo.osgeo.org/service/rest/repository/browse/release/org/geotools/gt-wfs-ng/25.2/).

My code is like this:

```
Integer Id = 27;
String featureType = "parcels"

// create store
connectionParams.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", serviceUrl+"?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS");
connectionParams.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:LENIENT", true);
connectionParams.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.BUFFER_SIZE.key, 1000);
connectionParams.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.TIMEOUT.key, 100000);
WFSDataStoreFactory factory = new WFSDataStoreFactory();
WFSDataStore dataStore = factory.createDataStore(connectionParams);
// feature store
SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource(featureType);
// create filter/query
Query query = new Query(featureType);
String filterString = String.format("%s = %s","Feature_ID", Id);
Filter filter = CQL.toFilter(filterString);
query.setFilter(filter);
// query feature store
SimpleFeatureCollection features = source.getFeatures(query);
SpatialIndexFeatureCollection index = new SpatialIndexFeatureCollection(features.getSchema());
index.addAll(features);
```

It crashes at last line(index.addAll) with this error:

> Exception: null, StackTrace: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at
> org.geotools.filter.capability.SpatialCapabiltiesImpl.addAll(SpatialCapabiltiesImpl.java:105)
> at
> org.geotools.filter.capability.FilterCapabilitiesImpl.addAll(FilterCapabilitiesImpl.java:189)
> at org.geotools.filter.Capabilities.addAll(Capabilities.java:570)   at
> org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.AbstractWFSStrategy.splitFilters(AbstractWFSStrategy.java:603) ...

From inspecting all the workflow I guess, that the null pointer for SpatialCapabilities and filter capabilities is caused by empty Filter_Capabilities element in getCapabilities xml.

I would like to know if my guess is right and if so, if there is some other way I can get features from wfs with geotools or any other public library in java. Any help will be very appreciated.

Here is [GetCapabilities response](http://matus.beeweb.sk/tempFiles/WFSServer_getCapabilities.xml).
Here is [spring log file](http://matus.beeweb.sk/tempFiles/spring_log.txt).

Comment: can you add the server address? that should not cause a crash,

Comment: do you mean "serviceUrl" variable in my case? ... I can post it here, but it is not a public WFS, so that will be of no use... However I can provide xml with getCapabilites, DescribeFeature xml for particular feature type if that may help... and I can even provide result of getFeatures... do you wish anything of this? ...

Comment: a copy of the getcapabilities would be best - but with out the actual server it is unlikely that I can solve the problem

Comment: I have added link to getCapabilities to the question... Unfortunately I can't provide access to that server, it is completely out of my reach... thank you ...

Comment: Hmm - can you a) check you are definitely using 25.2 as all your line numbers are slightly out, and b) add the full log when you have logging turned up to DEBUG

Comment: yes, I can confirm taht I am using 25.2 from repo that is stated in the question... I put link to log file to the question... thank you ...